# How to make multiple read more read less buttons in the same one page

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

What am I doing wrong here? I put each one into a separate ID however it still isn't working on my code. Please help it's for an assignment due in a few days!

```js
function readMoreRome() { //finds function
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots"); //returns element that has the ID attribute with value, searches for dots
    var moreText = document.getElementById("more"); // '' '' searches for more
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn"); // '' '' searches for myBtn

    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; //button says read more to show more text
        moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; //button says read less to show less text
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
    }
}

function readMoreBuda() { //finds function
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots2"); //returns element that has the ID attribute with value
    var moreText = document.getElementById("more2"); // '' '' searches for more2
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn2"); // '' '' searches for myBtn2

    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; //button says read more to show more text
        moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; //button says read less to show less text
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <h2>Visit Budapest</h2>
    <div class="info"> <span class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> November 12, 2019</span> <span class="comment"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i> 2 comments</span> </div>
    <div class="img"><img src="img/szechenyi.jpg" style="height:200px;"> </div>
    <p><i>Széchenyi Thermal Baths </i></p>
    <p>
        Budapest is the capital city of Hungary. It is best known for its arts and culture. It is a relatively small city, however there are much to see and do.
        <span id="dots2">...</span>
        <span id="more2">Situated on thermal springs, there are many naturally heated baths to relax in, the Széchenyi baths are the largest with 15 indoor baths and 3 outdoor. There are many spectacular viewpoints in Budapest, great for capturing the views of the city. From 360 panoramic views up at St Stephens Basilica to a wide view of the parliament and the River at Fisherman’s Bastion. Visit the Museum of Fine Arts and enjoy a day amongst famous European art. Classical music lovers will appreciate a performance at the Academy of Music.</span>
    </p>
    <button onclick="readMoreBuda()" id="myBtn2">Read more</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="card">
    <h2>Visit Barcelona</h2>
    <div class="info"> <span class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> December 06, 2019</span> <span class="comment"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i> 5 comments</span> </div>
    <div class="img"><img src="img/guell-park.jpg" style="height:200px;"></div>
    <p><i>Park Güell </i></p>
    <p>
        Barcelona, framed for its individuality, cultural interest, and physical beauty, home to art and architecture. Facing the Mediterranean to the southeast,
        <span id="dots3">...</span>
        <span id="more3"> the city is one of a kind. Upon visiting make sure you visit the spectacular and unique Park Güell which was firstly designed for a town up in the mountains by artist Antoni Gaudí. Gaudí's work is admired by architects around the World as being one of the most unique and distinctive styles in modern architecture. Other places worth visiting is the La Sagrada Família, is a giant basilica. With beaches on your doorstop, and art and city culture, this diverse city has everything to offer.</span>
    </p>
    <button onclick="readMoreBarca()" id="myBtn3">Read more</button>
</div>
```

It works the first time, however the button doesn't work for the second? I changed the ID but it still isn't working. It works however it states the read more with all the text outward first, you have to click it multiple times for it to reconnect and work.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you are not defining `readMoreBarca()`... You define `readMoreRome()` but this is never used.

You have code duplication, this is a bad practice, you should have a parameterized function like this:

```js
function readMore(city) {
    let dots = document.querySelector(`.card[data-city="${city}"] .dots`);
    let moreText = document.querySelector(`.card[data-city="${city}"] .more`); 
    let btnText = document.querySelector(`.card[data-city="${city}"] .myBtn`);

    if (dots.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        btnText.textContent = "Read more";
        moreText.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        btnText.textContent = "Read less"; 
        moreText.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="card" data-city="buda">
    <h2>Visit Budapest</h2>
    <div class="info"> <span class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> November 12, 2019</span> <span class="comment"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i> 2 comments</span> </div>
    <div class="img"><img src="img/szechenyi.jpg" style="height:200px;"> </div>
    <p><i>Széchenyi Thermal Baths </i></p>
    <p>
        Budapest is the capital city of Hungary. It is best known for its arts and culture. It is a relatively small city, however there are much to see and do.
        <span class="dots">...</span>
        <span class="more" style="display: none;">Situated on thermal springs, there are many naturally heated baths to relax in, the Széchenyi baths are the largest with 15 indoor baths and 3 outdoor. There are many spectacular viewpoints in Budapest, great for capturing the views of the city. From 360 panoramic views up at St Stephens Basilica to a wide view of the parliament and the River at Fisherman’s Bastion. Visit the Museum of Fine Arts and enjoy a day amongst famous European art. Classical music lovers will appreciate a performance at the Academy of Music.</span>
    </p>
    <button onclick="readMore('buda')" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
<br>
<div class="card" data-city="barca">
    <h2>Visit Barcelona</h2>
    <div class="info"> <span class="date"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> December 06, 2019</span> <span class="comment"><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i> 5 comments</span> </div>
    <div class="img"><img src="img/guell-park.jpg" style="height:200px;"></div>
    <p><i>Park Güell </i></p>
    <p>
        Barcelona, framed for its individuality, cultural interest, and physical beauty, home to art and architecture. Facing the Mediterranean to the southeast,
        <span class="dots">...</span>
        <span class="more" style="display: none;"> the city is one of a kind. Upon visiting make sure you visit the spectacular and unique Park Güell which was firstly designed for a town up in the mountains by artist Antoni Gaudí. Gaudí's work is admired by architects around the World as being one of the most unique and distinctive styles in modern architecture. Other places worth visiting is the La Sagrada Família, is a giant basilica. With beaches on your doorstop, and art and city culture, this diverse city has everything to offer.</span>
    </p>
    <button onclick="readMore('barca')" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is clarification code for those who are looking for a more specific example from code posted above.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title> Show More/Less </title>

 <style>
 .j { width: 30em; text-align: justify; }
 .hide { display: none; }
 .pink { background-color: tan;  color: white; }
 b, span { cursor: pointer; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<p class="j">Budapest is the capital city of Hungary. 
It is best known for its arts and culture. 
It is a relatively small city, however there are much to see and do.

 <b class="pink" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip;</b>

 <span class="hide" onclick="spanEllipse(this)">
Situated on thermal springs, there are many naturally heated baths to relax in, 
the Széchenyi baths are the largest with 15 indoor baths and 3 outdoor. 
There are many spectacular viewpoints in Budapest, great for capturing the views of the city. 
From 360 panoramic views up at St Stephens Basilica to a wide view of the parliament 
and the River at Fisherman’s Bastion. Visit the Museum of Fine Arts and enjoy a day amongst 
famous European art. Classical music lovers will appreciate a performance at the Academy of Music. 
</span>
</p>

<p class="j">
Barcelona, framed for its individuality, cultural interest, and physical beauty, home to art and architecture. 
Facing the Mediterranean to the southeast,

 <b class="pink" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip;</b>

 <span class="hide" onclick="spanEllipse(this)">
the city is one of a kind. Upon visiting make sure you visit the spectacular and unique Park Güell 
which was firstly designed for a town up in the mountains by artist Antoni Gaudí. 
Gaudí's work is admired by architects around the World as being one of the most unique and distinctive 
styles in modern architecture. Other places worth visiting is the La Sagrada Família, is a giant basilica. 
With beaches on your doorstop, and art and city culture, this diverse city has everything to offer.
 </span>
</p>

<script>
// For: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?364215-Show-only-first-line-of-a-paragraph&p=1508263#post1508263
function evtEllipse(info) {
  info.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
  info.classList.toggle('hide');
}
function spanEllipse(info) {
  info.classList.toggle('hide');
  info.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide')
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach to your problem.
There are 3 ways to display (initText(), initWords() and initLines().
Choose whichever you want to use and remove the others (as desired).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title> Ellipse </title>

<style>
 .j { width: 30em; text-align: justify; }
 .hide { display: none; }
 .pink { background-color: tan;  color: white; }
 b, span { cursor: pointer; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<p class="j">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, 
 sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 <b class="pink" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip;</b>
 <span class="hide" onclick="spanEllipse(this)">
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea
  commodi consequatur.    Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </span>
</p>

<p class="j">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, 
sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
 <b class="pink" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip;</b>
 <span class="hide" onclick="spanEllipse(this)">
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis     suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea
  commodi consequatur.    Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate     velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
  Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 </span>
</p>


<!-- Code below for same effect with random words/lines generated -->

<p class="j"><span class="gibber"></span> <!-- random english words or     sentences -->
 <b class="pink" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip;</b>
 <span class="hide gibber" onclick="spanEllipse(this)"></span>
</p>

<p class="j"><span class="gibber"></span>
 <b class="pink" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip;</b>
 <span class="hide gibber" onclick="spanEllipse(this)"></span>
</p>

<p class="j"><span class="gibber"></span> 
 <b class="pink" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip;</b>
 <span class="hide gibber" onclick="spanEllipse(this)"></span>
</p>

<p class="j"><span class="gibber"></span> 
 <b class="pink" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip;</b>
 <span class="hide gibber" onclick="spanEllipse(this)"></span>
</p>

<p class="j" style="background:wheat"><span class="gibber"></span> 
 <b class="pink" onclick="evtEllipse(this)">&hellip;</b>
 <span class="hide gibber" onclick="spanEllipse(this)"></span>
</p>

<script>
// For: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?364215-Show-    only-first-line-of-a-paragraph&p=1508263#post1508263
function evtEllipse(info) {
  info.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
  info.classList.toggle('hide');
}
function spanEllipse(info) {
  info.classList.toggle('hide');
  info.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide')
}
</script>

<script>
var gibberish = 
  `Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their     country. 
   Whatever the mind of man can conceive and believe, he can achieve. 
   The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog. 
   Do it now for now is the only time you have. 
   All looks yellow to a jaundice eye. 
   Always drink upstream from the herd. 
   Don't squat with your spurs on. 
   You can always learn a new way of being stupid.
   Look for new friends everywhere.
   Be alert.  The world needs more lerts!
   Mistakes do not last a lifetime. Forgive often.`;

var lorumIpsum =
  `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, 
   sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis
   suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur.
   Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
   dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat     non
   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est     laborum.`;

function filltext(count, info=gibberish) {
  var str = '', gibber = info.replace(/\s+/g,' ').split(' ');
  for (var i=0; i<count; i++) str +=         gibber[Math.floor(Math.random()*gibber.length)]+" ";
  return str;
}

function fillWords(count, info=gibberish) {
  var str = '', gibber = info.split(' ');
  for (var i=0; i<count; i++) str +=     gibber[Math.floor(Math.random()*gibber.length)]+" ";
  return str;
}

function fillLines(count, info=gibberish) {
  var str = '', gibber = info.split('\n');
//  for (var i=0; i<count; i++) str +=     gibber[Math.floor(Math.random()*gibber.length)]+"\n";
  var f = Math.floor(Math.random()*gibber.length);  // form random         number
//  for (var i=0; i<count; i++) { str += gibber[f]+"\n"; f++; f = (f %     gibber.length); }
//  return str;

  var rstr = [];
  for (var i=0; i<count; i++) { rstr.push( gibber[f] ); f++; f = (f %     gibber.length); }
  return rstr.join('\n');
}


// Note: can mix & match gibberish & lorumIpsum in code below

// initialize for filltext version
function initText() {  
  let count = 0;
  const sel = document.querySelectorAll('.gibber');
  for (el of sel) {
    if (count % 2 == 0) { el.append(fillWords(10, gibberish)); } 
                   else { el.append(fillWords(50, lorumIpsum)); }
    count++;
  }
}

// initialize for fillWords version
function initWords() {  
  let count = 0;
  const sel = document.querySelectorAll('.gibber');
  for (el of sel) {
    if (count % 2 == 0) { el.append(fillWords(10, lorumIpsum)); } 
                   else { el.append(fillWords(50, lorumIpsum)); }
    count++;
  }
}

// initialize for fillLines version 
function initLines() {
  let count = 0;
  const sel = document.querySelectorAll('.gibber');
  for (el of sel) {
    if (count % 2 == 0) { el.append(fillLines(1, gibberish)); } 
                   else { el.append(fillLines(5, gibberish)); }
    count++;
  }
}

// initText();
// initWords();
initLines();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this supposed to help? Its not related at all.

Comment: The contents of the read more/less sections in this example are for display of some lines/words/characters only.  They are meant to be gibberish.  The important parts are the layout portion of the HTML and the JS functions.  They can be used to create the read more/less displays.  Will be glad to provide a more specific example if requested.

Comment: Here is clarification code for those who are looking for a more specific example from code posted above.

    `

Answer (score 0):

check out this code and method how to use - here use different methodology for achieving the goal

```js
function readMoreFun(param, param_id) {
  let elements = document.getElementsByClassName(param);
  let element_id = document.getElementById(param_id);
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.toggle("hidden-content");
  }
  element_id.classList.toggle("hidden-readmore");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

.item h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
  color: #813131;
}

.item p {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande",
    "Lucida Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  word-spacing: 1.6px;
}

.hidden-content {
  display: none;
}

.read_more {
  color: #61b1f1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.read_more:hover {
  color: #488ad6;
}
.hidden-readmore {
  display: none;
}
.read_less {
  color: #0f60bd;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <h3>what is Gravity?</h3>
    <p>Gravity is a fundamental force of nature that is responsible for the attraction between objects with mass. It is one of the four fundamental forces in the universe, along with electromagnetism, the strong nuclear force, and the weak nuclear force. Gravity was first described by Sir Isaac Newton in the late 17th century and later refined by Albert Einstein's theory of general relativity in the early 20th century.<a id="read_more_1" onclick="readMoreFun('hide_seek-1',this.id)" class="read_more">...Read More</a></p>
    <div class="hide_seek-1 hidden-content">
      <p>Attraction of Mass: Gravity is a force that attracts all objects with mass towards each other. The more massive an object is, the stronger its gravitational pull. This is why planets, stars, and other massive celestial bodies have strong gravitational fields.</p>
      <p>Inverse Square Law: According to Newton's law of universal gravitation, the force of gravity between two objects is directly proportional to the product of their masses and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between their centers. Mathematically, it can be expressed as:</p>
      <p>Acceleration Due to Gravity: All objects near the surface of the Earth experience a gravitational acceleration towards its center. On Earth, this acceleration is approximately 9.81 meters per second squared (m/s²). This means that for every second an object is in free fall, its speed increases by 9.81 meters per second.<a onclick="readMoreFun('hide_seek-1','read_more_1')" class="read_less">...Read Less</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>what is Gravity?</h3>
    <p>Gravity is a fundamental force of nature that is responsible for the attraction between objects with mass. It is one of the four fundamental forces in the universe, along with electromagnetism, the strong nuclear force, and the weak nuclear force. Gravity was first described by Sir Isaac Newton in the late 17th century and later refined by Albert Einstein's theory of general relativity in the early 20th century.<a id="read_more_2" onclick="readMoreFun('hide_seek-2',this.id)" class="read_more">...Read More</a></p>
    <div class="hide_seek-2 hidden-content">
      <p>Attraction of Mass: Gravity is a force that attracts all objects with mass towards each other. The more massive an object is, the stronger its gravitational pull. This is why planets, stars, and other massive celestial bodies have strong gravitational fields.</p>
      <p>Inverse Square Law: According to Newton's law of universal gravitation, the force of gravity between two objects is directly proportional to the product of their masses and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between their centers. Mathematically, it can be expressed as:</p>
      <p>Acceleration Due to Gravity: All objects near the surface of the Earth experience a gravitational acceleration towards its center. On Earth, this acceleration is approximately 9.81 meters per second squared (m/s²). This means that for every second an object is in free fall, its speed increases by 9.81 meters per second.<a onclick="readMoreFun('hide_seek-2','read_more_2')" class="read_less">...Read Less</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>what is Gravity?</h3>
    <p>Gravity is a fundamental force of nature that is responsible for the attraction between objects with mass. It is one of the four fundamental forces in the universe, along with electromagnetism, the strong nuclear force, and the weak nuclear force. Gravity was first described by Sir Isaac Newton in the late 17th century and later refined by Albert Einstein's theory of general relativity in the early 20th century.<a id="read_more_3" onclick="readMoreFun('hide_seek_3',this.id)" class="read_more">...Read More</a></p>
    <div class="hide_seek_3 hidden-content">
      <p>Attraction of Mass: Gravity is a force that attracts all objects with mass towards each other. The more massive an object is, the stronger its gravitational pull. This is why planets, stars, and other massive celestial bodies have strong gravitational fields.</p>
      <p>Inverse Square Law: According to Newton's law of universal gravitation, the force of gravity between two objects is directly proportional to the product of their masses and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between their centers. Mathematically, it can be expressed as:</p>
      <p>Acceleration Due to Gravity: All objects near the surface of the Earth experience a gravitational acceleration towards its center. On Earth, this acceleration is approximately 9.81 meters per second squared (m/s²). This means that for every second an object is in free fall, its speed increases by 9.81 meters per second.<a onclick="readMoreFun('hide_seek_3','read_more_3')" class="read_less">...Read Less</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <h3>what is Gravity?</h3>
    <p>Gravity is a fundamental force of nature that is responsible for the attraction between objects with mass. It is one of the four fundamental forces in the universe, along with electromagnetism, the strong nuclear force, and the weak nuclear force. Gravity was first described by Sir Isaac Newton in the late 17th century and later refined by Albert Einstein's theory of general relativity in the early 20th century.<a id="read_more_4" onclick="readMoreFun('hide_seek_4',this.id)" class="read_more ">...Read More</a></p>
    <div class="hide_seek_4 hidden-content">
      <p>Attraction of Mass: Gravity is a force that attracts all objects with mass towards each other. The more massive an object is, the stronger its gravitational pull. This is why planets, stars, and other massive celestial bodies have strong gravitational fields.</p>
      <p>Inverse Square Law: According to Newton's law of universal gravitation, the force of gravity between two objects is directly proportional to the product of their masses and inversely proportional to the square of the distance between their centers. Mathematically, it can be expressed as:</p>
      <p>Acceleration Due to Gravity: All objects near the surface of the Earth experience a gravitational acceleration towards its center. On Earth, this acceleration is approximately 9.81 meters per second squared (m/s²). This means that for every second an object is in free fall, its speed increases by 9.81 meters per second.<a onclick="readMoreFun('hide_seek_4','read_more_4')" class="read_less">...Read Less</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).